# Using Python to zip and list functions to combine two 2D arrays to produce x,y coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays, list, zip

I have two, 2D-arrays each of dimensions 831 x 918. If:

Matrix A =[[a(1,1), a(1,2),...],[a(2,1),a(2,2)...]] 
Matrix B =[[b(1,1), b(1,2),...],[b(2,1),b(2,2)...]]

I would like to combine the two matrices to create a list with ((a(1,1),b(1,1)),(a(1,2),b(1,2)),...).

What is the best way to do this? I have tried to use the zip and list functions as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ly=fits.open(lightyield.fits)
ly=ly[0].data
dx=fits.open(de.fits)
dx=dx[0].data
combo=list(zip(dx,ly))
```

However, this returns a list that is 831 elements long, but each position on the list has a lot of elements. I only want to have a single (x,y) point for each element in the list, not an entire array.

Thanks for any help. 
EDIT: As a basic example, for:
 A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
 B=[[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]

I want to get a list to plot of ((1,10),(2,11),(3,12),...).

Comment: Can you share a specific example and expected output?

Comment: `a(2,2)` appears twice in Matrix A; is this a typo?

Comment: Typo fixed and example with expected output added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two arrays of the same shape like:

```
a = np.random.random((10, 15))
b = np.random.random((10, 15))
```

You can perform this operation to get a list with the pairs of elements in the same position

```
[(a_, b_) for a_, b_ in zip(a.flatten(), b.flatten())]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You can also replace the zip with `np.stack((a.flatten(), b.flatten()), axis=-1)`

Comment: Yeah, and you wuold have to reshape later, but it looks cleaner, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If both are numpy arrays, you can use pure numpy functions and methods:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3,3)
B = np.arange(10, 19).reshape(3,3)

pairs = np.stack((A,B), axis=2).reshape(-1, 2)
"""
array([[ 1, 10],
   [ 2, 11],
   [ 3, 12],
   [ 4, 13],
   [ 5, 14],
   [ 6, 15],
   [ 7, 16],
   [ 8, 17],
   [ 9, 18]])
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it as...convert A and B to np object of shape=(813,918) then

```
 result = np.vstack((A[0],B[0])).T
```